# Confusion regarding the use of the residue theorem in complex analysis.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

I have been studying about the residue theorem and I am a little confused about the way the theorem is used.For example considering the function: $$f(z)=\frac {1}{1-z}+\frac{2}{2-z} $$ this function will have three different power expansions.First for $|z|<1$ we get that:
$$S_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+2^{-n})z^n$$ for $1<|z|<2$  :
$$S_2(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(z^n2^{-n}-z^{-n})$$
and for $|z|>2$  :
$$S_3(z)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+2^n}{z^n}$$

My confusion arises when I have to use the residue theorem for an integral like say:
$$I=\oint_C f(z)dz$$ where $C$ contains both singularities $z_1=1$ and $z_2=2$. So by the residue theorem, we get that $$I=2\pi i\sum_{k\in\{1,2\}}\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z_k)$$ However, are the residues that are going to be summed the $\alpha_{-1}$ terms of the power expansions $S_2$ and $S_3$ or do we have to express the function as a power sum of $(z-1)^n$ and $(z-2)^n$  where $n\in \mathbb Z$ to find the terms that we want to sum up? (I am aware of the residue formula but I am trying to see what happens without necessarily using it)

Comment: Deform the contour into tight circles around the poles connected by paths.

Comment: Residues are computed locally around a point $p$, that is, in a punctured neighbourhood $p$. Thus, you want to compute the Laurent expansion in powers of $z-p$ and look at the coefficient of $z^{-1}$. All the power series you wrote down are not informing about the local behaviour around $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the series expansion **around** $z=1$, not for $|z|<1$ or $1<|z|<2$. It should be something like $\sum_n a_n (z-1)^n$. The same for $z=2$.